# Request not accepting Authorization header for every second request

Tags: go, go-gin

### Description

I have an API which I have created and I have some endpoints protected. The problem I am facing now on the client making a request is that the first request comes through with the Authorization header provided but a second request is blocked because Authorization is not present.
I can confirm that Authorization is present and worked perfectly when I was running Typescript till I recreated the endpoints in Go with Gin.

### How to reproduce

- Call estimate endpoint from client (iOS app) response succeceds
- Make a second call from Client (iOS app) response failed because it is not taking the Authorization header which contains token

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type App struct {
    Router   *gin.Engine
    Gateman  *gateman.Gateman
    Database *mongo.Client
}

func (a *App) StartApp() {

    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not load .env \n")
    }

    a.Database = database.DB
    a.Router = gin.New()

    a.Gateman = middleware.Gateman()
    a.Router.Use(gin.Recovery())

    a.Router.Use(middleware.DefaultHelmet())

    a.Router.Use(middleware.GinContextToContextMiddleware())
    a.Router.Use(middleware.RequestID(nil))
    a.Router.Use(middleware.ErrorHandler())
    a.Router.Use(middleware.Logger("package-service"))

    connection, err := amqp091.Dial(os.Getenv("AMQP_URL"))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Printf("Error on dial %v\n", err.Error()))
    }
    routes.Routes(a.Router, database.GetDatabase(a.Database), a.Gateman, connection)

}

func (a *App) Run(addr string) {
    logs := log.New(os.Stdout, "package-service", log.LstdFlags)

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         addr,
        Handler:      a.Router,
        ErrorLog:     logs,
        IdleTimeout:  120 * time.Second, // max time for connections using TCP Keep-Alive
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

    go func() {
        if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            logs.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    // trap sigterm or interrupt and gracefully shutdown the server
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Kill)

    sig := <-c
    logs.Println("Recieved terminate, graceful shutdown", sig)
    tc, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    server.Shutdown(tc)
}

func Routes(r *gin.Engine, db *mongo.Database, g *gateman.Gateman, conn *amqp091.Connection) {

    atHandler := pc.NewPackagesController(ps.NewPackagesService(pr.NewPackagesRepository(db)), g, events.NewEventEmitter(conn))

    r.Use(CORS())
    v1 := r.Group("/api/v1/package")
    {
        v1.POST("/query", GraphqlHandler(db, directives.NewDirectivesManager(g)))
        v1.GET("/", PlaygroundHandler(db))
        v1.POST("/", g.Guard([]string{"user"}, nil), atHandler.Create)
        v1.POST("/estimate", g.Guard([]string{"user"}, nil), atHandler.Estimate)
        v1.PUT("/:packageID", g.Guard([]string{"user", "admin"}, nil), atHandler.Update)
        v1.PUT("/:packageID/assign", g.Guard([]string{"admin"}, nil), atHandler.Assign)
        v1.POST("/:packageID/cancel", g.Guard([]string{"user", "admin"}, nil), atHandler.CancelRequest)
        v1.POST("/:packageID/complete", g.Guard([]string{"admin"}, nil), atHandler.Complete)
        v1.POST("/:packageID/reject", g.Guard([]string{"admin"}, nil), atHandler.RejectRequest)

        v1.GET("/healthz", atHandler.GetHealth)

    }
    r.GET("/", atHandler.GetUP)
}

func CORS() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}

func main() {
    start := App{}
    start.StartApp()
    start.Run(":3009")
}
```

### Expectations

All endpoints that are Guarded simply checks the header for Authorization and if provided in the request, it should be successful

### Actual result

First request succeed `/estimate`
Second request `/` POST request fails to accept Authorization header

Also irrespective of what the first post request is, the second post request just never accept the `Authorization` header

Also need to mention that I do not have this issue with postman. Both request run independently but using another client for the request, gives this problem

### Environment

- go version: 1.19
- gin version (or commit ref): v1.8.1
- operating system: Mac and iOS mobile

Here is my client code

```
func request<T>(with builder: BaseRequest) -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError> where T: Codable {
        request(with: builder, customDecoder: JSONDecoder())
    }
    func request<T>(with builder: BaseRequest, customDecoder: JSONDecoder) -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError> where T: Codable {
        
        let encoding: ParametersEncoder = [.get, .delete].contains(builder.method) ? URLParameretersEncoder() : JSONParametersEncoder()
        customDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        var url: URL {
            var components = URLComponents()
            components.scheme = "https"
            components.host = builder.baseUrl
            components.path = "/api/v1" + builder.path
            
            guard let url = components.url else {
                preconditionFailure("Invalid URL components: \(components)")
            }
            
            return url
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 46.0)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = builder.method.rawValue
        builder.headers.forEach { key, value in
            urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
        if let token = tokenManager.token {
            urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
//            urlRequest.setValue("ABC", forHTTPHeaderField: "testing123")
        }
        
        if let parameters = builder.parameters {
            guard let encoded = try? encoding.encode(parameters: parameters, in: urlRequest) else {
                fatalError()
            }
            urlRequest = encoded
        }
        self.log(request: urlRequest)
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .mapError {_  -> APIError in
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                return .unknown
                
            }
            .flatMap { data, response -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError> in
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    return Fail(error: APIError.invalidResponse).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                self.log(response: response, data: data, error: nil)
                if (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) {
                    return Just(data)
                        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: customDecoder)
//                        .map {
//                            print($0)
//                            return $0
//                        } //added
                        .mapError {
                            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                            return .decodingError(underlyingError: $0)
                            
                        }
                    
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    if response.statusCode == 401 {
                        // Send notification to remove corrdinator and return to root
//                        rxNotificationCenter.post(.invalidToken)
                    }
                    guard let errorResponse = try? customDecoder.decode(BaseResponse.self, from: data) else {
                        return Fail(error: APIError.decodingError(underlyingError: NSError("Can't decode error"))).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    }
                    return Fail(error: APIError.server(response: errorResponse))
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }


protocol BaseRequest {
    var baseUrl: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var headers: HTTPHeaders { get }
    var method: HTTPRequestMethod { get }
    var parameters: HTTPParameters { get }
}

public typealias HTTPHeaders = [String: String]
public typealias HTTPParameters = [String: Any]?
```

Another point, calling a single endpoint multiple time, works fine, calling a different one is where the header is rejected

Comment: I doubt the issue is on the server-side, so I would investigate & update the question to show your iOS client-side code.

Comment: I would update it. The authorization works for the first request but does not not for the second one, I then passed a dummy header as part of the request header and the dummy header is present but Authorization is not. Also when I changed the name from just `Authorization` to `Authorizationxzy`, I see the value.

Comment: Another point, calling a single endpoint multiple time, works fine, calling a different one is where the header is rejected

Comment: I think I can pin the problem down now. A weird problem.

In my request, I am using 

`/api/v1/package` this was causing a 307 redirect. It expected me to use `/api/v1/package/` which is weird.

Comment: See [RedirectTrailingSlash](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.RedirectTrailingSlash) in the engine configuration.